# Kafka fs2 stream how to set a backpressure

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, fs2

i have fs2 stream from kafka topic, is it possible to set, how much of data can be pulled? Be cause, currently i have a problem, if in the middle of a stream a problem occures, it end up with a memory spike. So basically to prevent this, i want to set, how much of data can a stream pull and process before pulling a new batch.

Comment: may be is it possible to set a memory limit for fs2 stream?

Answer (score 0):

Backpressure is automatic with fs2 because it's a pull-based system, not push-based. Streams request more data from their source when they need to use it.

You can control the message buffering during construction; see the docs [here](https://fd4s.github.io/fs2-kafka/docs/consumers#settings)

`withMaxPrefetchBatches` looks like a relevant setting